# org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Table Authorities doesn't exist

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Spring 3.1, Hibernate 4 and Primefaces application. It works fine on my local machine but when I deploy the ant generated war file on my web host, then  iget an error when i try to login.

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Table 'brutteng_adaptiveonlinetesting.Authorities' doesn't exist
```

I have created the database at my web host which has the authorities table. I took the matter with the web host support team but they suggested the it is due to the case of table but I doubt it as I am not using the table name anywhere. It is used by Hibernate with the capital 'A' in Authorities table name.

Looking forward for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly they are right and table names are case-insensitive in database on your local machine and case-sensitive in web host. That would explain why problem does not occur in your local setup, where case in script does not matter too much.

Capitalize first character of the table name in the script and likely it will work in both.

Comment: But on the webhost, the table names are all in lowercase. This is the authorities.hbm.xml : 
    <class name="iltaf.models.Authorities" table="authorities" catalog="brutteng_adaptiveonlinetesting">
        <composite-id name="id" class="iltaf.models.AuthoritiesId">
            <key-property name="username" type="string">
                <column name="username" length="50" />
            </key-property>
            <key-property name="authority" type="string">
                <column name="authority" length="50" />
            </key-property>
        </composite-id>
    </class>

Comment: Hey Mikko, I love you. It worked. I only renamed the table from authorities to Authorities at my web host database and it worked like a charm :)